# Modifying a Linked List in C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I want to change the value in a linked list. The list is defined as

```
struct car_elements {
    char *car_rego;
    double time_parked;
    struct car_elements *next;
};

typedef struct car_elements car;
```

I have created a linked list that has 10 elements. I can change the time_parked easily but having trouble updating char *car_rego. To create the string

```
char *rego_array = malloc(7*sizeof(char));
CreateCarRego(rego_array);
```

The definition for CreateCarRego is

```
void *CreateCarRego(char *rego_array)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int w = 0; w < 6; w++)
    {
        if (w < 3)
        {
            temp = GenerateRandomNumber(26.0);
            temp = temp + ASC_TO_LETTER;
            rego_array[w] = (char)temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = GenerateRandomNumber(10.0);
            temp = temp + ASC_TO_NUMBER;
            rego_array[w] = (char)temp;
        }
        rego_array[7] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Then to change the value

```
car *current_carpark = head; //head holds the linked list

for (int i = 1; i < carspace_number; i++) {  //I know which element I want to change
    current_carpark = current_carpark->next;
}

current_carpark->car_rego = (char*)calloc(strlen(rego_array), sizeof(char));
strncpy(current_carpark->car_rego, rego_array, strlen(rego_array));
```

This works but now I have a memory leak - I cannot free current_carpark. With the struct definition I have what is the best way to create a string (which is just 3 random letters and 3 random number) and update car_rego. I cannot just use

```
current_carpark->car_rego = rego_array;
```

As nothing is stored. I am new to C and yes this is an assignment however I have tried and tried to get this to work with no success

Comment: As-used in this code, dynamic allocation of car_rego is pointless. You can save yourself quite a bit of code by just using a `char car_rego[7]` as the member in the struct. (and stay within your array boundaries (0..6) to avoid undefined behavior, btw).

Comment: Why can't you do `current_carpark->car_rego = rego_array;` ?

Comment: You are not allowed to access `rego_array[7]`, either increase size of `malloc`'ed memory, or use `6` as last index of array.

Comment: I did as you suggested and changed the struct - the question now is that is I have created char rego_array[7] and it is populated how do I then add it to the struct strcpy(current_carpark->time_parked , rego_array);

Comment: Worked it out strncpy(current_carpark->car_rego , rego_array, 6);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has **out of bounds `char *`** issues.

---

In `CreateCarRego()`, change

```
rego_array[7] = '\0';
```

to

```
rego_array[6] = '\0';
```

It is good to put the NUL terminator on, but it is done in the wrong place.  `rego_array` is 7 bytes long and the 7th byte is accessed via `rego_array[6]`.

---

Change

```
current_carpark->car_rego = (char*)calloc(strlen(rego_array), sizeof(char));
strncpy(current_carpark->car_rego, rego_array, strlen(rego_array));
```

to

```
current_carpark->car_rego = malloc(strlen(rego_array) + 1);
strcpy(current_carpark->car_rego, rego_array);
```

Not enough memory is allocated using only the length of the string,  one needs the length of the string + 1.  The following `strncpy()` limit is too tight, it should also be `strlen(rego_array) + 1`.  As it is known that the destniation is long enough, `strcpy()` could be used.

*or*

Simplify the string duplication with

```
current_carpark->car_rego = strdup(rego_array);
```

---

A number of improvements could also be mentioned, but the above should get rid of memeory problems.